# WSDL with Includes

Tags: java, soap, xsd, wsdl, dom4j

What is the right way to read a WSDL with XSD includes into org.dom4j.io.SAXReader?  Is there a way to do it using ZipInputStream so that I don't have to persist it to disk?

Comment: You need to elaborate on your problem, since it is unclear what you mean with "include". Do you want to validate a WSDL document against an XSD schema that is referenced from the WSDL, or literally included? BTW, DOM4J is not capable of doing  schema validation on its own.